# Login page not redirecting in Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-authentication

Building a Django project where in I want that the password is been set by the admin, anyone who wants to access the same needs to use that particular password only.
to implement the same I made a custom User model and a custom authentication backend.

But when putting in input in the login form the page isn't getting redirected.

here is the **backend.py** file :

```
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from main.models import CustomUser
    class AdminSetPasswordBackend(ModelBackend):
        def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
            try:
                user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
                if user.is_active and user.check_password(password) and user.admin_set_password:
                    return user
            except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
                return None
```

Here is the **CustomUser Model in my models.py**:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    admin_set_password = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adharcardNo = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    # Add any other fields you need

    # Provide unique related_name for groups and user_permissions
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        related_name='custom_user_groups',
        blank=True,
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
        verbose_name='groups',
    )

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        related_name='custom_user_permissions',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        verbose_name='user permissions',
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

here is the **views.py** file handling the request :

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    
    template_name ='main/login.html' # Update with the path to your login template
    
    success_url = 'main/classselect.html
```

this is the **urlpattern** added to handle the same :

```
path('login/', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

And the **login.html template**:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Assistanza</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
     <!-- login.html -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="id_username">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" required>
                <br>
                <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" required>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```